# How to enable-disable input type="text" when select value from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

I have a drop-down list) and one is input type="text". what i want if i select value{2,3} from drop down list not first value then input type will be disabled and if i select again first value then it will be enable.

Comment: Can you show the code you have written thus far?

Comment: Please add a MCVE to your questions posted on stackoverflow: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose you have this HTML code:

```
<select id='dropdown'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="textInput" />
```

Then you can act on  `change` event on `<select>` to make `<input>` disabled or enabled by adding an event listener.

Since you're using jQuery (as you've added `jquery` tag to the question), the example code could look like this:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
    if( $(this).val() == 1) {
        $('#textInput').prop( "disabled", false );
    } else {       
        $('#textInput').prop( "disabled", true );
    }
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/2268/

Comment: Is There any way we can do this in php or wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the select box's `onchange` event. If you set the first item to some known value (like an empty string, or "first" or whatever), you can check the current value and disable or enable the text box based on that.

```js
var sel = document.getElementById("sel"), text = document.getElementById("text");

sel.onchange = function(e) {
  text.disabled = (sel.value !== "");
};
```

```html
<select id="sel">
  <option value="">1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

Comment: input text will be enable first time or first value.

Comment: Okay. You can reverse the logic, then.

Comment: Thanks! Its Working.